# How does the spinglass algorithm work when used for community detection in networks?

Tags: network, spin-models

I am reading the article "Statistical Mechanics of Community Detection" by Jörg Reichardt and Stefarn Bornholdt, which describes how to use the spinglass model from physics to determine communities in networks. They say that they use simulated annealing, but do not describe exactly how - they just refer to the article "Optimization by Simulated Annealing" (1983) which explains the method in general. So I would like to know more precisely how the method from the older article is implemented in the newer article. Specifically, I would like to know what is used as a random generator of moves - i.e. how are the nodes are moved between communities in each time step.